# How can I modify my code to only add even numbers?

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm supposed to write a procedure that takes user input and finds the sum of only the even numbers. I've written the code so that it finds the sum of all the inputs but i'm not sure how I can modify it to only add even inputs together.

```
(define even
  (lambda()
    (accumulator 0 0 (read))))

(define accumulator
  (lambda(sum n next) 
     (if (not (number? next))
         (compute-sum sum n)
         (accumulator (+ n sum) (+ 1 n)(read)))))

(define compute-sum
  (lambda(sum n)
    (if (> n 0)(+ sum n)
        "no number")))

(even)
```

If the input is 1 2 3 4 5 end, the output should be 6

Answer (score 1):

```
(define even
  (lambda()
    (accumulator 0 0 (read))))

(define accumulator
  (lambda(sum n next) 
    (if (not (number? next))
        (compute-sum sum n)
        ; Problem 1: (accumulator (+ n sum) (+ 1 n)(read)))))
        (if (even? next)
            (accumulator (+ next sum) (+ 1 n) (read))
            (accumulator sum (+ 1 n) (read))))))

(define compute-sum
  (lambda(sum n)
    ; Problem 2: (if (> n 0)(+ sum n)
    (if (> n 0) sum
        "no number")))

(even)
```

**Problem 1**: The recursive call should add `next` to the `sum` based on whether or not it's even.

**Problem 2**: The final result should not add `n` to the `sum`, it should just return the sum.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `for/sum` in Racket:

```
(define (sum-even data)
  (for/sum ([x (in-list data)] #:when (and (number? x) (even? x))) x))

> (sum-even '(1 2 3 4 5 "end"))
6
```